# Swift - render image with relative path in markdown

Tags: ios, swift, image, markdown

I'm saving images as follows:

```
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
let url = NSURL(string:"http://cdn.businessoffashion.com/site/uploads/2014/09/Karl-Lagerfeld-Self-Portrait-Courtesy.jpg")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:url!)
if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
    let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("2.png")
    if let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        pngImageData.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: false)
    }
}
```

And I am using [Markingbird](https://github.com/kristopherjohnson/Markingbird) to render some text with embedded images. URLs work fine, but I cannot find the correct relative path to my saved images. It's definitely being saved properly.

I've tried all of the following:

- `![Alt text](1.png)`
- `![Alt text](Documents/1.png)`
- `![Alt text](/Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/993FB5AC-etc/data/Containers/Data/Application/8F8A924A-etc/Documents/1.png)`

Is there a better place to save downloaded images? And how do I find the relative path to saved images?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the most direct answer that you are looking for but may solve your problem.

I've created Markdown image support for `NSAttributedString` as a fork of excellent `CocoaMarkdown` library.

It's available here: https://github.com/X8/CocoaMarkdown

It support parsing *images* along with caching it on the device. You can see approach I used in `CMImageAttachmentManager`.

I use it in projects with Swift and Obj-C so it should be ok with you.

And now to focus more on your answer - I think you are much better off with using some lib which enables to download and cache images, like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/SDWebImage) or [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift). Why? They take care of cacheing which in the long run will save quite a lot of data for your users. Moreover, they are tested and reliable piece of code.